# Adobe Digital Editions does not work on my Apple Mac

Tags: mojave

I can download books from my local library to my computer but Adobe Digital Editions does not open them. I wish to transfer them to my Kobo Glo. This has worked in the past.
My Mac is Mojave 10.14.6.  I get this message when I try to open a book with ADE version 4.5: - E_AUTH_BAD_DEVICE_KEY_OR_PKCS12. Error getting licence. Licence Server Communication Problem.
I also tried ADE versions 2.1, and 3. I get this message: E_ACT_NOT_READY

I have tried removing ADE 4.5 to the Trash and emptying the Trash and then reinstalling it.
I have tried to deauthorise ADE on my computer in order to reauthorise it but am unable to do this. There is no option to deauthorise ADE 2.1 or 3.0.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Adobe products often have uninstallers, which must be run to completely remove the product. Beyond that, I suggest trying the Adobe forums.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm a bit of an amateur with Mac. Can you tell me how to find an uninstaller for this Adobe product?